# Mapping multiple Security Groups into ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to attach multiple security groups containing Cloudfront CIDRs to my AWS ALB.

```
locals {
  chunks = chunklist(data.aws_ip_ranges.cloudfront.cidr_blocks, 60)
  chunks_map = { for i in range(length(local.chunks)): i => local.chunks[i] }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  for_each = local.chunks_map
  name = "{each.key}"

  egress {
    ....
  }
}

resource "aws_elb" "load" {
  name = "test"
  security_groups = aws_security_group.sg.id // This is wrong
```

My error that I'm receiving is
`Because aws_security_group.sg has for_each se, its attributes must be access on specific instances`

Using for_each again doesn't make sense because i don't want to create multiple resources, I just want to ensure that all security groups created are attached to the load balancer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've used `for_each` there will be more than instance of `aws_security_group.sg`. To get `id` from all of them you can use [splat](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) operator:

```
security_groups = values(aws_security_group.sg)[*].id
```